# How does JavaFX deal with normal checking on projected Shape3Ds?

Tags: javafx, affinetransform, projection-matrix

I looked for a way to create shadows in 3D javaFX programs, and since I found none, I decided to make my own. It accomplishes this by taking the shape of the 3D model, and using a projection matrix to flatten it onto a surface (I'm using the Affine class to make this matrix. There are a couple issues with it, but the most pressing is the fact that Affine doesn't seem to update the normal vectors once the projection is complete, leaving a weird lighting issue. Similarly, it doesn't seem to update the information used by PerspectiveCamera when calculating distortions.
[image: The the bright face of the cylinder is projected down, but it keeps the brightness]

[image: PerspectiveCamera still thinks the shape has depth]